# - Dad, John doesn't want to go to school today! / - He shall!

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, conversation

How idiomatic is this dialogue?

-- Dad, John doesn't want to go to school today!
-- He shall! *(whether he likes it or not, and I will make sure he does!)*

Comment: When and where is this dialogue taking place? Is it a comtemporary setting or historic? In Britain, America or another part of the Engllish-speaking world?

Comment: 'Shall' is very formal, and this just doesn't fit the context. It's extremely unlikely in the UK (I'd expect "He's going, whether he likes it or not!") ... probably even less likely in the US. More likely in Dickensian times (though 'dad' is then unlikely).

Comment: Yes, but with a caveat. It would be accompanied by an attitude (voice) and another word: Ah, but he shall!

Comment: @Lambie How about 'Ah, but he will!' or 'Ah, but he will go!' ?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - it sounds like a typical dialogue in my house, except that my son is aged 44.

Comment: An interesting example of where *shall* is not used is the [code of conduct of the Supreme Court of the United States](https://www.supremecourt.gov/about/Code-of-Conduct-for-Justices_November_13_2023.pdf): it has the word *should* 52 times and *shall* 0 times.  If these were actually rules, then most of these cases of *should* could be written *shall*.

Comment: @Michael Harvey
 '_Shall_ is not used very much nowadays and mostly in formal speech and some legal documents.' [[Grammar.d](https://www.grammar.cl/english/shall.htm)] / 'In statements, _shall_ has the specific use of expressing an order or instruction, normally in elevated or formal register' [Wikipedia]. / ' "You shall" (most formal)' [[British English Lessons](https://www.britishenglishlessons.com/shall-and-shant/)]

Comment: @Henry:  Agreed. "Shall" in US legal language refers to a *requirement*.  It means "must". The code of conduct  seems to have deliberately avoided "shall" But we shouldn't take that to be any indication of the currency of the word **shall** "on the street", so to speak. Not that you're doing so. It's more like they're avoiding accountability.

Comment: Idiomatic would be "He's gotta, or he ain't gonna learn nuthin."

Answer (score 0):

> How idiomatic is this dialogue?

> -- Dad, John doesn't want to go to school today!
>
> -- He shall! (whether he likes it or not, and I will make sure he does!)

It is not idiomatic at all.

1. Shall is currently rare and has been for about 70 years.
2. Shall is usually used only in the 1st person (*I* and *we*.)
3. Shall refers back to the active verb, which is "want".
4. It is hard to think how you can force or order someone to want something.

Comment: So it would be correct to say 'He shall go!" ?

Comment: For commands, *shall* was used with the second and third persons.

Comment: @Quirkier: It would be *more* correct for you to forget about *ever* using "shall"! Most native speakers today are probably only really aware of it because the Fairy Godmother tells Cinderella: *"You **shall** go to the ball!"* (not a command, but a confident assertion / prediction).

Comment: @FumbleFingers no-one will buy me a drink and I shall go thirsty (or something like that)

Comment: Why does “shall” have to refer to the active verb? In the dialog “I don’t want to do the dishes!” “You *have to*!”,  in my dialect of English ( American) *“have to*” refers to *do* and not *want*. And I can’t imagine it’s different in British English.

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers, *shall* is a word you never need to use in 21st century English, unless you’re a lawyer. Teaching people to use it is only slightly less archaic than teaching them to use *thee* and *thou*.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: "By their fruits ye **shall** know them" (It's not *quite* "medieval phrasing, but we're definitely showing our age here! )

Comment: "Shall" is not rare today, but it is usually jargon.

Comment: I will say that "shall" is still used in some dialects of British English, but usually not Standard Southern British (when you do occasionally hear it used it's usually something affected, that is something someone's learnt artificially to "sound more posh" rather than being a natural part of their speech), and I can't recommend it for learners.

Comment: It is still idiomatic in technical documents, where it is important to have a clear distinction between requirement levels: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2119 . There it is synonymous with "must" and "required".